# Number column in Tlist window

Tags: vimrc, plugin-taglist

I want to hide the number column `set nonumber norealtivenumber` in `Tlist` window! Every time I call `:Tlist` the number column appears in the window.
How can I disable the number column for that window.

[image]

Comment: Where is Tlist from?

Comment: Taglist plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify specific commands for some file as the following:

```
autocmd BufEnter filename/pattern   set commands
```

I my case I have to explicitly hide the number column for the Tag List window:

```
autocmd BufEnter __Tag_List__   set nonumber norelativenumber
```

Comment: Remember to put your `autocommand` in an `augroup` as explained in [`:h autocmd-once`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-once) (And remember to accept your answer to show future readers that your question has an answer)

Comment: I'll check the `:h autocmd-once`, I have to wait 14 hours before I can accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If `:Tlist` comes from the [taglist](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/) plugin, from the docs, I can see :

> To not display the Vim fold column in the taglist window, set the
>   'Tlist_Enable_Fold_Column' variable to zero.

So in your .vimrc, do

```
let Tlist_Enable_Fold_Column=0
```

Note that this column helps you see how the folds are applied. You can toggle folds with `za`. For more infos about folds, see `:help folds` or `:h zo` to see fold mappings.

I would recommend you try a fuzzy finder plugin such as [CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) or [CommandT](https://github.com/wincent/command-t). With both, you can - in addition to search files, buffers, etc... - search in tags. With CtrlP, you can use `:CtrlPBufTagAll` to toggle the search, fuzzy find whatever you want, and jump to it.

Comment: Meh, plugins for tags is overkill. Vim is built to work with tags quite well. For fuzzy-file finding? Sure.

Comment: I don't mean the fold column, I mean the numbers column.

Comment: Indeed... did you try `autocmd FileType taglist set nonumber norelativenumber` ?

Comment: This works for me `autocmd BufEnter __Tag_List__   set nonumber norelativenumber`. The buffer title's name is `__Tag_List__`